# Linux kernel makefile cscope target

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, cscope

When I generate Linux kernel cscope database by issuing `make cscope` I get database file along with  a list of files with **relative** path. This is a problem for me because later on when I attach that external kernel's database in vim editor from whatever directory but kernel's I can easily search for specific symbol **BUT** I can't open file that symbol is contained in.

I've written the next bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

SNAME="$0"
SNAME=${SNAME##*/}

function usage()
{
    echo Generate Linux kernel cscope database
    echo "Usage: $SNAME [PATH]"
    echo -n "You must provide this script with an ABSOLUTE path of your "
    echo "kernel's root directory"
}

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    usage
    exit -1
fi

KDIR="$1"

echo -n "Collecting a list of files... "
if find "$KDIR" -path "${KDIR}/arch/*" ! -path "${KDIR}/arch/x86*" -prune -o \
        -path "${KDIR}/include/asm-*" \
        ! -path "${KDIR}/include/asm-generic*" \
        ! -path "${KDIR}/include/asm-x86*" -prune -o \
        -path "${KDIR}/tmp*" -prune -o \
        -path "${KDIR}/Documentation*" -prune -o \
        -path "${KDIR}/scripts*" -prune -o \
        -name "*.[chxsS]" -print > cscope.files; then
    echo done
else
    echo failed
fi

echo -n "Building cscope database... "
cscope -k -qb && echo done || echo failed
```

that collects all files I need (x86/x86_64 architecture) using **absolute** path and then I successfully build cscope database manually. But I think it must be some easier way to accomplish this. Maybe some Makefile's target like `make cscope_abs` or `make cscope_ext` that I have not found yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 did not know it has a make cscope option.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is : look into the Makefile how cscope is called, if there exists a variable you then can specify some options to cscope in command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the cscope manpage [here](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html):

> **-P path**
>       Prepend path to relative file names in a pre-built cross-reference file so you do not have to change to the directory where the
>   cross-reference file was built. This option is only valid with the -d
>   option.

So I guess the following command from the top-level kernel directory should do the trick (sorry no linux machine handy):

```
cscope -d -P `pwd`
```

my 2 cents,

Answer (score 5):

First, it is simpler to create a cscope database specific to a particular architecture as follows : In Linux kernel's top folder, run

```
ARCH=x86 make cscope
```

This creates a cscope with **relative** paths. 
Now you can ask vim to interpret the paths relative to the location of the cscope.out file in one of two ways:

**Way 1 :** Use `cscoperelative`. Output of `:help csre` :

```
If 'cscoperelative' is set, then in absence of a prefix given to cscope
(prefix is the argument of -P option of cscope), basename of cscope.out
location (usually the project root directory) will be used as the prefix
to construct an absolute path.  The default is off.  Note: This option is
only effective when cscope (cscopeprg) is initialized without a prefix
path (-P).  Examples: >
    :set csre
    :set nocsre
```

**Way 2 :** (From Aaron Hs' answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188405/how-to-let-cscope-use-absolute-path-in-cscope-out-file) question) When adding the cscope database in vim, specify base location. Example:

```
:cs add <base_location>/cscope.out <base_location>/
```

From vim's help page for cscope add:

```
USAGE   :cs add {file|dir} [pre-path] [flags]

    [pre-path] is the pathname used with the -P command to cscope.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
make cscope
```

or for your specific case -

```
ARCH=x86 make cscope
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command in the root of the kernel tree to generate   absolute paths:

```
#> make O=. cscope
```